# Flutter: Why default padding is 8.0?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I don't know about other IDE but VS Code automatically sets `EdgeInsets` to  8.0 when I wrap my widget with `Padding` widget. Is it a random number or has some logic behind it?

Comment: no, its not random, its fixed

Comment: @pskink I know I mean how is this number decided?

Comment: well, the most neutral value should be `0.0` - but the plugin authors decided that `8.0` is better, i agree with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the baseline grid size in Material Design being 8dp.

See:
https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#baseline-grid

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behavior for the Padding widget. Android Studio also doing the same. Because padding is required filed in Padding Widget.

```
const Padding({
   Key? key,
    required this.padding,
    Widget? child,
   }) : assert(padding != null),
      super(key: key, child: child);
```

Comment: Yes, I know the Padding widget does not have a default value. But he asked about the idea feature. That's why I am commenting on this. Thanks for your comment brother.

Comment: Brother, I am saying that if you wrap any widget with a padding widget, then android studio and visual studio code automatically set 8 padding value. I hope you understand.